# Chrome Extension communication via Content Scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to listen to events on a webpage by using Chrome Extension app build with React and Redux.

I've setup a content.js file that works as a content script and it can send messages to my React app just fine, the app can see the event properly... but there's an issue - I want to send MouseEvent (or any other Event, for that matter) data to my React app but my React app only recieves

```
data: {
 isTrusted: true
},
type: 'onPageClick',
```

So as you can see everything from the MouseEvent is gone, except for `isTrusted`. Do I need any special permission in `manifest.json`?

Files:

```
// manifest.json
{
  "short_name": "Example Extension",
  "name": "Example Extension",
  "icons": {
    //...
  },
  "content_security_policy": "...",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "background"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Example Extension"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [ "content.js"],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

```
// content.js

document.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  console.log(ev);

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('EXTENSION-ID', {
    type: 'onPageClick',
    data: ev,
  });
});
```

```
  // fragment of App.js
  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((...args) => console.log(args));
  }, []);
```

Is it even possible to send event data? I've been able to send custom JSON objects without any issues, but every field from Event gets removed when sending the message.

Thanks!

Comment: DOM Events are not JSON-serializable so no you can't send them. You can extract all fields you want and send a new object though.

Comment: Weird, I kinda tried that... with no results. I'll try later today and let you know if it worked. Thank you!